# Passing values to ng-model from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I have a form that passes its inputs to `ng-model` before storing to the database. One of which is a dynamic value (pre-generated code) that is taken from its database table.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="codes in response | filter: {branch: formData.branches.alias, taken: 0} | limitTo: 1">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" ng-model="formData.code" ng-value="codes.code" readonly="" />
</div>
```

Theoretically, once the `ng-model` gets the value, it then passes it to the `insert` call for the database to store it along with the rest of the fields.

```
scope.processForm = function(isValid){
    scope.$submitted = true;

    if(isValid && state.$current=='registration.signupapp') {
        http.post("server/insert.php",{'code': scope.codes.code, 'fullname': scope.formData.name, 'instagram': scope.formData.igname, 'email': scope.formData.email, 'mobile': scope.formData.mobile, 'location': scope.formData.location.type, 'branch': scope.formData.branches.branch}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log("inserted successfully");
    });
        state.go('registration.success');
    } else if(!isValid) {
        //alert("Please make sure that you entered everything correctly.");
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. 1) I was told that you cannot simply pass an `ng-value` to an `ng-model` inside an `input[text]`. 2) Even if in the case that the value is passed to `ng-model`, I am not sure what to call inside the controller as `scope.codes.code` nor `scope.formData.code` do not seem to work and gets either a `not defined` error or `404`.

In a nutshell, how do I:

- Get the value generated by `ng-repeat` as set to `limitTo:1`.
- Store it to `ng-model` in real-time (as this is very dependent on a
  dynamic dropdown).
- Pass the value of `ng-model` back to the `controller`.
- Send it back to the server and store it to the database.

Comment: I seems to me that you already have the data in your controller scope as 'response'.  Rather than use ng-repeat to get one value, just use the filter service and set the value of formData.code in the controller scope.

Comment: Can you give me a gist of that by code so I can have a clearer idea of what you are saying?

Comment: Added a short demo to the answer.  I think this is what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: If you only intend to set the value of model while ng-repeat does it's job then i guess ng-init is what you are looking for... see my answer for implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess ng-init should help you out here.

Change your code segment from:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="codes in response | filter: {branch: formData.branches.alias, taken: 0} | limitTo: 1">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" ng-model="formData.code" ng-value="codes.code" readonly="" />
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="codes in response | filter: {branch: formData.branches.alias, taken: 0} | limitTo: 1" ng-init="formData.code=codes.code">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" ng-model="formData.code" readonly="" />
</div>
```

Comment: This one looks waaaaay simpler. This is using what's already available. I think this works better on my current setup. Thanks a lot, man!

Answer (score 1):

This is really contrived, but here's a very simplified demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.filter('myFilter', function(){
  return function(data){
    return data[0];
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter){
  var myfilter = $filter('myFilter');
  
  $scope.response = ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005'];
  
  $scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
  
  $scope.formData = {};
  
  $scope.$watch('formData.select', function(newval){
    if (newval === 'Item 1') {
      $scope.formData.code = myfilter($scope.response);
    } else {
      $scope.formData.code = '';
    }
  });
  
}]);
```

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <pre>formData.code = {{formData.code || "No Code for this Item"}}</pre>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Select a Value: <em>Choose Item 1 to update formData.code</em></label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="formData.select" ng-options="item as item for item in items"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>formData.code:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" ng-model="formData.code"  />
  </div>
</div>
```

You have the response already, so rather than use ng-repeat, just add the value to the formData.code on the controller.  If you need to use a custom filter, you can pass in the $filter service as a dependency to your controller.

**Edit:**

I didn't notice the part about the formData.code being dependent on another form value, so I updated the demo to include a $watch function.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am quite new with using the filters inside a controller that's why I asked. I think your code works if it is a straight assignment of an array to `scope.response`. Mine is being fetched from the database via the `server/fetch.php` file. For some reason, `scope.response` is an `undefined` object, and returns `[]` when converted to an array. Is there a difference of  that from just a straight on assignment of an array like you did?

Comment: Yes, the difference is that you're asynchronously getting the values so you'd have to make sure that the response has been assigned, but it looks like someone else already gave you an answer you prefer.  That's cool.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks to you too, @jme11. I probably will take note of what you gave me, and might use that in the future. Thank you very much.